# Initializer for array of pointers in C multiarray

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

When building a multi-index array in C, it is possible to leave "open" the first index, either via a pointer

```
#define A 3
#define B 5
#define C 2

double aux[A][B][C] = {[0 ... A-1][0 ... B-1][0 ... C-1]=1.0};
double (*s)[B][C] = aux;
```

or simply with the array notation (but in this case I do not know how to use the auxiliary variable)

```
double s[][B][C] = {[0 ... A-1][0 ... B-1][0 ... C-1]=1.0};
```

Now, if we want to leave open an intermediate index, `s[A][][C]`, I think the only solution is to declare an array of pointers, isn't it? For `A=3`, the following two initializations work

```
double (*t[A])[C] =  {aux[0],aux[1],aux[2]};
double (**u)[C] =  t;
```

and we can use `t[i][j][k]` or `u[i][j][k]` in the main code.

But consider `A = 100`. Is there some way to declare all the `aux[0...A-1]` pointers in a compact way in the initializer? , or somehow "cast" `aux` into `t` or into `u`?

**Note**: as Jonathan points out, triple-dot is a gcc extension. For this question, well, I am happy to initialize to zero anyway, or having  a random aux. An answer just reserving memory, such as

```
double aux[A][B][C];
double (*t[A])[C] =  (miraculous cast) aux[];
double (**u)[C] =  t;
```

would be enough, if triple-dots and initializers can not help.

**possible hint?**: If I do

```
double *trivial[A] = {aux[0],aux[1],aux[2]};
double (**v)[C] =  trivial;
```

I get an interesting (multiple) warning, repeated for each assignment in the initializer

```
warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'double *' with an expression of type 'double [5][2]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
double *trivial[A] = {aux[0],aux[1],aux[2]};
```

Comment: Be aware that the triple-dot range notation in designated initializers is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: Gut feel: the answer is "No".  But I've not worked out how to verify that conclusion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the problem is that the examples in the standard put some limitations to compound literals. The one for p=(int [2]) {*q} seems to invite to set zeros unneededly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to declare all the aux[0...A-1] pointers in a
> compact way in the initializer?

No, you'd run a little loop like

```
for (int i=0; i<A; i++) t[i] = aux[i];
```

and though it looks like this is doing 'more work', in fact any compiler worth its salt will make this just as fast as a really compact-looking initializer. In other words, if there was a compact notation for this kind of thing, the actual assignment steps would still have to be done, and they would be the same as this loop.

> , or somehow "cast" aux into t or into u?

Well, here's the thing - sorry if this is trivial to you but I think it is relevant. Whenever you use `aux` in your code after its definition, it is *automatically turned into the relevant pointer*. So you may wish to have a pointer `t[2]` to the start of the last 5x2 block of doubles of your array, but `aux[2]` is exactly that. As the C18 standard says in §6.3.2.1, item 3:

> an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object

so the 5x2 array `aux[2]` is turned into a pointer-to-array-of-2-doubles, like the ones you were storing in `t`.

If you `#include <assert.h>` and put this in your code,

```
assert(t[1] == aux[1]);
assert(u[1] == aux[1]);
assert(t[1][3] == aux[1][3]);
assert(u[1][3] == aux[1][3]);
```

there will be no 'Assertion failed' errors. So you might as well start with `t = aux;` or `u = aux;` or just use `aux` itself whenever you need the appropriate pointer.

Regarding the 'possible hint' from your compiler warning: the statement

```
double *trivial[A]
```

declares `trivial` as an array of 3 pointers-to-double. The initialization then tries to assign to `trivial[0]` (a pointer-to-double) the value of `aux[0]`, a pointer-to-array-of-2-doubles, hence the warning. That's why you can't omit the `()[C]` from your original version.